# botao é acionado sem eu clicar - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    let aplicarCor = function(elemento, cor){
        elemento = ("#" + elemento);
        $(elemento).css("background-color", cor);
    };

    $("#laranja").on("click", (aplicarCor("funcoesComEventos", "orange")));
    $("#verde").on("click", (aplicarCor("funcoesComEventos", "green")));
    $("#gray").on("click", (aplicarCor("funcoesComEventos", "gray")));
```

Answer (score 4):

O método `on` do JQuery espera uma função de *callback* como segundo parâmetro, mas você não está passando uma função, está invocando a função e passando o retorno dela.

Você pode corrigir isso declarando uma função de callback, que invoca a sua função `aplicarCor`.

```
let aplicarCor = function(elemento, cor){
    elemento = ("#" + elemento);
    $(elemento).css("background-color", cor);
};

$("#laranja").on("click", () => aplicarCor("funcoesComEventos", "orange"));
$("#verde").on("click", () => aplicarCor("funcoesComEventos", "green"));
$("#gray").on("click", () => aplicarCor("funcoesComEventos", "gray"));
```

Note que essa abstração só é necessário porque você está invocando a função `aplicarCor` com parâmetros diferentes em cada chamada, se a função `aplicarCor` não recebesse nenhum parâmetro, você poderia escrever simplesmente

```
$("#laranja").on("click", aplicarCor);
```